# XSL: nested <?choose?> in RTF Template

Tags: xslt, bi-publisher

I'm having trouble getting my RTF template to accept a nested choose in my first cell.  I have:

```
<?choose?>
  <?when: FIRST_COLOR='Red'?>
    <?FIELD_VALUE?>
  <?end when?>
  <?otherwise?>
    <?choose?>
      <?when: SECOND_COLOR?>
        <?xdofx:FIELD_VALUE_2||'Z'?>
      <?end when?>
      <?otherwise?>
        <?FIELD_VALUE_2?>
      <?end otherwise?>
    <?end choose?>
  <?end otherwise?> 
<?end choose?>
```

I also tried without the colon in the when statements, but instead of an error, I only get two out of 50 records.

Answer (score 0):

I found that a nested if worked instead.

```
<?xdofx:if FIRST_COLOR='Red' then
    FIELD_VALUE
  else
  if SECOND_COLOR!='' then
    FIELD_VALUE_2||'Z'
  else 
    FIELD_VALUE_2
end if?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your original example was the code you were actually using, you were missing colons.  It should be:

`<?otherwise:?>`

That would cause an issue, but I cannot say whether it would have caused your issue since you did not specify the exact error you were getting.